# Add local lib in pom.xml but not found when running war file

Tags: maven

My develop env is eclipse STS.
I am stuck in this issue as follow:

First add local jar file in pom.xml

    `<dependency>
        <groupId>testjdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.1.2032</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/patch/testjdbc.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>`

It is ok in develop environment not compile error and I check this file also in pakcge file after packaged this project.
But it is not found when running in STS Server.

I have checked "Browse Deployment Location" and testjdbc.jar does not existed.

Answer (score 0):

This works as designed. System scope dependencies will not be packed into your application.

> **provided** This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK
>   or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when
>   building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
>   set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
>   scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This
>   scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is
>   not transitive.
>
> **system** This scope is similar to provided except that you have to
>   provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always
>   available and is not looked up in a repository.

See [Maven Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)